# regex help please specific letters and 3 digit numbers

Tags: regex

I need letters `A-F` only in capitals which is `^[A-F]`.
I then need 3 digit numbers only, from 001 to 140.

I have this

```
(0?[0-9]?[0-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-9]|13[0-9]|14[0])$
```

but that isn't limiting to 3 digits.

anyone able to assist please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
/[A-F](00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-3][0-9]|140)/
```

If it's first the character and then the number as I seem to understand from your description.